# Am I taking the right direction with the logic?

Tags: javascript, recursion, iteration

Let's assume I have the following elements somewhere in my HTML:

```
<div class="container">
    <div class="box first">I have a height of 100</div>
    <div class="box">I have a height of 200</div>
    <div class="box last">I have a height of 300</div>
</div>
<div class="container">
    <div class="box first">I have a height of 50</div>
    <div class="box">I have a height of 60</div>
    <div class="box last">I have a height of 40</div>
</div>
```

What is the correct logic to set the height of each box to match the highest box within its container?

My thinking goes something like this:

1. For each element in the document, check if it has class "container"
2. For each child element of "container" check if it has class "box"
3. If it does, add its reference to an array and compare its height with a variable which contains the last checked element's height, if it's greater then assign it to the variable
4. Set the height of each element in the array to the value of the height

...am I on the right course here?

Comment: Instead of "for each element check …", use `getElementsBy…` (in your case, a class selector).

Comment: I don't think you're on the right course if you're trying to set the height via JavaScript - it should be possible with pure CSS. What are you trying to achieve?

Comment: I think you guys are missing the point. If I select all the elements in the document with getEelementsBy... then they will *all* get assigned the height of the tallest element in the document. This is not the goal. The goal is to have all 3 boxes in the first container be the same height (the height of the tallest box in just that container) and so on...

Comment: @bernk: I did not say you should select them in the document's context. First, use `containers = document.getElementsByClassName("container");` then use `children = containers[i].getElementsByClassName("box")`.

Comment: @PrasathK: No, he has three `div.box` elements in each container.

Comment: @Bergi See my answer and his class names are different box first,box,box last..

Comment: @PrasathK: All three divs have the `box` class, the first and last one also have additional classes which don't matter us here.

Comment: Ok i accept but my answer also works fine for this case

Comment: It's not working yet, but this is where I'm going with this. Thanks for the feedback guys! http://jsfiddle.net/bernk/NBnW9/4/

Answer (score 1):

Have a look on this..

1. Get the elements with class name 'container'

   ```
   var container = document.getElementsByClassName('container');
   ```
2. For each container

   1. get the 'div' elements using

      ```
      var box_div = container[index].getElementsByTagName('div');
      ```

      or

      ```
      var box_div = container[index].getElementsByClassName('box');
      ```
   2. Check the maximum height of the divs
   3. Set the maximum height to all other divs

Comment: Instead of `.getElementsByTagName('div')`, you might use only the `.children` collection - simpler, and less errorprone if the boxes could have descendant divs.

Comment: Thank you for the edit .. Still now , i was thinking that class names box first,box and box last are different class names and came to know they are additional classes to box class .. I learnt this here .. Check my edited post